# How do you tell whether UIImagePickerController cameraOverlayview will rotate or not?

Tags: ios, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

IOS 6 on the Ipad rotates the UIImagePickerController cameraOverlayView on landscape mode, but IOS 6 on the iphone 3GS does not - thank you Apple!

I dont know the behaviour for IOS 5, or other devices, so is there a way of predicting this behaviour so i can apply a rotation transform on the overlay view?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. Here's what I discovered:

In the Target's "iPad Deployment Info" config, make sure you've enabled "Landscape Left" and "Landscape Right" modes - even if your app doesn't really support these (this can be done through the info.plist file as well, obviously).

[image]

Next, in your `UIViewController`(s), force them to Portrait:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

Now the `UIImagePickerController` should rotate correctly when the iPad is rotated to landscape - but your `UIViewController` will still be Portrait-only.

Comment: Sorry, that doesnt fix the overlay not rotating - and only on the iphone! thanks for the input.